# Execute JqueryMobile Popup on Jquery timing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, timing

I am having trouble attaching a timing event to my function I want this to on execute the function after 25 seconds. what am I doing wrong?

```
    setTimeout("ajaxTimeout();", 25000);

        $(document).on({

//open popup here
'pageshow': function ajaxTimeout(){
    $('#askforsomething').popup('open');
}
}, '#homepage');
```

Comment: I edited with-out explanation sorry, I found out jquery doesn't set the timeout function automatically so now I am trying to accomplish it in javascript and jquery. still no luck thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. You probably mean `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`. Alternatively, a shorthand for this is simply `$(function () { ... })`.
2. You can (and should) pass a function to `setTimeout` instead of a code string.

Result:

```js
$(function () {

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#askforsomething').popup('open');
  }, 25000);

});
```

Comment: I marked yours as the right answer since it's a lesser complicated version 8-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the logic behind it but this did work for me. and the guy above looks like he was pretty close to the same.

```
 $(document).on({

//open popup here
"pageshow": function () {

    setTimeout("$('#askaquestion').popup('open');", 15000);
}
}, "#homepage");
```

Comment: Just did and it works fine as well and a bit less typing. nice 8-)